# How to write robust type wrappers around Eigen::Matrix

Tags: c++, types, wrapper, eigen

I wanted to introduce type wrappers for Eigen's 2d vectors for both possible component orderings. My very first try was this

```
using RowCol = Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::Index, 2, 1>;
using ColRow = Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::Index, 2, 1>;
```

This has the problem that it silently convert from either type to the other. I'd like to get a compile error if that ever happens. My next try was therefore

```
using Matrix_t = Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::Index, 2, 1>;
struct ColRow;
struct RowCol : public Matrix_t 
{
    using Matrix_t::Matrix_t;
};

struct ColRow : public Matrix_t 
{
    using Matrix_t::Matrix_t;
};
```

This already disallows conversion from compound types like `vector<RowCol>` to `vector<ColRow>` but due to `Eigen::Matrix`'s default ctor `Matrix(const EigenBase<OtherDerived> &other)`, this still allows direct conversions from `RowCol` to `ColRow`. Therefore I tried to delete the according ctors and assignment operators which is the best solution I've come up with so far.

```
struct ColRow;
struct RowCol : public Matrix_t 
{
    using Matrix_t::Matrix_t;
    RowCol(const ColRow&) = delete;
    RowCol& operator=(const ColRow&) = delete;
    RowCol& operator=(ColRow&&) = delete;
};

struct ColRow : public Matrix_t 
{
    using Matrix_t::Matrix_t;
    ColRow(const RowCol&) = delete;
    ColRow& operator=(const RowCol&) = delete;
    ColRow& operator=(RowCol&&) = delete;
};
```

This works quite ok. The only downside is that I now have to be more verbose at some call-sites

```
RowCol rc;
rc = rc.cwiseMin(...);  // doesn't compile because operator= is ambiguous, could be RowCol& operator=(const ColRow&) or ColRow& operator=(const RowCol&)
rc = RowCol{rc.cwiseMin(...)};  // must be explicit
```

Is there a way to improve on that without losing any type-safety?

Comment: Could you be more specific, which operations are supposed to work and which not? E.g., `rc = 2*rc; cr = rc + cr;` ...

Comment: I thought there might be some kind of well-established pattern to solve this. If not and at all possible, it would be nice if at least your first expression or anything where I implicitly convert from underlying Eigen-types to one of my types would be possible without explicit construction.

Comment: I guess just inserting `using Matrix_t::operator=;` should allow assigning Eigen-expressions (or types) directly. But of course, the return types of `rc.cwiseMin(...)` and `cr.cwiseMin(...)` will be the same, so you can't easily prohibit one but allow the other.